# Plotting based on all previous equation results

Tags: plotting

I have a plot

```
Plot[40500*x^(-0.1), {x, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 50000}]
```

Now, I am trying to plot the cumulative of these y values. I'll try to explain on an example:

> for x=1: 40500*1^(-0.1) 
>   for x=2: 40500*(2^(-0.1)+1^(-0.1)) 
>   for x=3: 40500*(3^(-0.1)+2^(-0.1)+1^(-0.1)) 
>   and so on up to x=100.

Is there a way to do that? I can't think of one. Thanks!

Comment: Look up `Table` and `Accumulate`.  `Plot` assumes `x` to be continuous while you seem to treat is as discrete.

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually, it would be awesome if this could be done continuously as in case with `Plot` and be a very smooth graph.

Comment: @user30479 That's not what your example shows ("...x=1...x=2...x=3...").  Could you clarify?  `Plot` generates the curve by discrete sampling and links the points with straight line segments. It tries to sample finely enough that the eye does not see the angles.  It does this irregularly, so accumulating its sample values has little mathematical meaning.  For a "continuous" accumulation, perhaps you want to plot the integral (see `Integrate`).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ahh, okay. Sorry, I don't know mathematica that much, so I didn't know that. So, to clarify, what I need is a smooth curve. I don't care how it's done really whether it's `Plot` or `Integrate`. It's just that I don't want to to look like a `ListLinePlot[{{1,10},{2,35},{3,45}}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think wha you want is the integral of your expression.

```
f[x_] = Integrate[40500*x^(-0.1), x];
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 100}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: omg, I'm dumb. Thank you so much!